# Writing to the STDIN of a C program from PHP

Tags: php, c, stdout, stdin, popen

I literally have almost no PHP experience at all whatsoever. I have a C program that I'd like to put online (it's computationally intense, I'd rather keep it in C), so my question is this: How to I write to the STDIN of a C program using PHP (and read from it's STDOUT)? Like, taking a string from an HTML form, or something similar, and writing that to the STDIN.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short, check this out: http://php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [System program execution](http://docs.php.net/exec) section of the manual.
Esp. [proc_open — Execute a command and open file pointers for input/output](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php)

You could also pass the parameter as an argument to the executable and fetch the output which can easily be done via [escapeshellarg()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) and [exec()](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php)

You might also be interested in http://www.swig.org/

> SWIG is a software development tool that connects programs written in C and C++ with a variety of high-level programming languages. SWIG is used with different types of target languages including common scripting languages such as Perl, PHP, Python, Tcl and Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`fwrite`](http://php.net/fwrite) and [`fget`](http://php.net/fwrite)

```
fwrite(STDOUT, "\n-CMD$: "); //Output 
$site = fgets(STDIN)   // Get Input
```

Answer (score 0):

If your php program just echoes strings (using echo),

```
php -f program.php | c_program
```